# How can I configure Apache CXF ignoreNamespaces in TomEE+?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I have create a simple RESTful service but when I tried to return json I have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid JSON namespace
```

Looking at TomEE+ 1.7.1 I saw behind jax-rs implementation there is Apache CXF 2.6.4, so I tried to configure property ignoreNamespaces = true.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation on TomEE, and looking at Apache CXF documentation if I want set ignoreNamespaces = true I should set it into `beans.xml`

Should I try to use a different implementation (Jersey)?

Comment: Let us see your jsonnamespaceMap bean

Comment: @KarthikPrasad jsonnamespaceMap was a misconfigured parameter. I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into `cxf.xml` or `beans.xml`:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
<bean id="jaxbJSONProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
<property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true"/>
</bean> 
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Comment: +1 This is working for me instead using the Jackson (fasterxml) which was failing in my case. Downvoters should comment in what the answer could be improved.